# Formally proving that $\{ L = { {a^i}{b^j}{c^k}, j = \min(i,k), i, k > 0\} } $ is context-free

Tags: computer-science, formal-languages, context-free-grammar, pumping-lemma

**Please no hints**.

I need to formally prove that $\{  L = { {a^i}{b^j}{c^k}\mid  j = \min(i,k),\: i, k > 0\} } $:

At first my idea was to use pumping lemma, so I tried to study where $\\|vwx|\ $falls but it seems that for some cases the pumped string is accepted, this led me to thinking that pumping lemma couldn't work, so I separated  $ \ L = L1 \bigcup L2 $, because CF languages are closed under union, with :

$\{  L1 = { {a^i}{b^i}{c^k} | 0 < i < k\} } $

$\{  L2 = { {a^i}{b^k}{c^k} | 0 < k < i\} } $

The problem is also with L1 and L2 I can't work this out with pumping lemma.  Actually I even can't decide a good $p$ for

$\\|vwx|\ = p$

I tried using concatenation with ${a^+}{b^+}$ but then I get stuck.
I tried to write a grammar for both $L1$ and $L2$ but was no use.
Can someone show me the way this exercise is meant to be done? I would really appreciate it.

Comment: The pumping lemma can only show that languages are NOT context-free, not that they are

Comment: That's what I wrote. At first i thought it was not CF, then I realized it was and I changed approach.

Comment: The language is not CF and you can prove that with the pumping lemma. (As requested, no hints although it is tempting :-) )

Comment: @rici no hints means i need a solution, not a generic statement.

Comment: @niciola: Sorry, I thought you wanted to solve this problem yourself. Solution provided. The importance of the possibility of setting $n=0$ is often underemphasised.

Comment: The pumping lemma will tell you that the language is not regular. It can still be context free.

Comment: @JohnDouma; There are many pumping lemmas, including [one for context-free languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_context-free_languages)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The language is not context-free, and that can be demonstrated with the pumping lemma.

Suppose $L$ were context-free. Take the sentence $\omega=a^pb^pc^p$, which is certainly in $L$. The pumping lemma says that if $L$ is context-free, then $\omega$ contains a substring $vwx$ whose length is less than $p$ which can be replaced with $v^nwx^n$ for any integer $n\ge 0$ to yield another sentence in the language.

The length restriction means that $vwx$ contains at most two different symbols, since it cannot span from $a$ to $c$. In order for the replacement $vwx\to vvwxx$ to produce a sentence in $L$, it's necessary for $v$ and $x$ to be repetitions of a single symbol; otherwise $vv$ (resp. $xx$) would contain either $ba$ or $cb$, which cannot be substrings of a sentence in $L$. So that reduces to the following cases:

1. $v$ and $x$ are repetitions of $a$ or both repetitions of $c$. Chose $n=0$ so that the replacement is $vwx\to w$. Since the count of $b$ is not reduced, it no longer has the same length as the minimum.
2. $v$ and $x$ are both repetitions of $b$. Chose $n=2$; now there are more $b$ than either $a$ or $c$.
3. One of $v$ and $x$ consists of repetitions of $b$ and the other one doesn't. Choose $n=2$. Now there are more $b$ than there are of whichever of $a$ and $c$ was not increased.

Consequently, the sentence $a^pb^pc^p$ cannot be pumped, contradicting the assertion that $L$ is context-free.

Comment: What if $u$ and $v$ are both repetitions of $a$ or $c$ but one of the two is equal to $max(i,k)$? For istance: if $b$ has equal repetitions as $c$, this means that $j = k$, but i'm pumping $a$'s, then my pumped string is still inside $L$. In that case, then what?

Comment: and What if $u$ and $v$ falls between $a$ and $b$ , and $j=i$(or between $b$ and $c$ and $j=k$), with both $u$ and $v$ not equal to lambda? Then if I pump the same number of letters in $a$ and %b%, and the number of $i$ is still less than $k$, I would still have $i=j$ and $j = min(i,k)$. This string is still inside L. Same for $b$ and $c$ but with inversion of $i$'s and $k$'s. Then what?

Comment: @niciola: In the given sentence, $i=j=k=p$. If $u$ and $v$ are both $a$ and you choose $n=0$, then you have $i'=i-|u|-|v| < j$. The fact that the sentence I chose has $i=j=k$ is important. Note that in the pumping lemma game, I get to choose the initial sentence, and then the opponent gets to choose the decomposition, subject to the rules

Comment: Why is setting $i=j=k=p$ enough to prove my point? I thought I should have done more to prove it, also with different numbers of $i,j$ inside my string.

Comment: Because the pumping lemma says that if $L$ is context-free, any sentence $\omega \in L$ can be pumped. So I only have to find one sentence $\omega$ which cannot be pumped. And I've demonstrated that $a^pb^bc^p$ cannot be pumped. Hence $L$ is not context-free.

Comment: (Technically, it says that every sentence in $L$ whose length is at least $p$ can be pumped. But evidently $|a^pb^pc^p| \ge p$.)

Comment: Wow I was actually missing this detail. Thanks!

Comment: Last question: What does it mean that $i'= i - |u| - |v| < j$? $i=j$, and $n=0$, so why now $i < j$? And why you wrote $uuvww$ and not $uvwxy$?

Comment: I guess I should have used $vwx$ instead of $uvw$ to conform with standard notation. I changed it in the answer. ($u$ and $y$ in the standard notation are just there in order to say that $vwx$ is a (contiguous) substring, which seems to me a more intuitive way to think about things.) The pumping lemma says you can replace $vwx$ with $v^nwx^n$; if $n=2$, that means replacing it with $vvwxx$. If $n=0$, that means replacing it with $w$. You can work out the resulting $i, j, k$ yourself; the formula I gave is what happens when you set $n=0$ and the entire substring is $a$s.

Comment: If you pump with $n=0$, you are not adding strings but subtracting them instead from $a$ or $b$, am I right?

Comment: Yes, that's what pumping with $n=0$ means. Nowhere does the pumping lemma say "adding strings" :-) That's just the way people to seem to think about it. But $n=0$ is a perfectly legitimate pump and often useful (as in this case).

Comment: Well... Actually, even though the formal explaination of the pumping lemma never says "add strings", the verb to pump means $inflate, fill, draw$. Its etymology has french origins, and being italian I use the word "pompare" (to pump) every day with that meaning. This is why maybe some student might not seem conscious of the real meaning of the pumping lemma.

Comment: @niciola: yes, mathematics does not always use terms in the way we might be accustomed. But then, French uses $personne$ to mean nobody, so go figure. Zeroness is often unintuitive, or even unsettling. Anyway, good luck with your studies.